# Zend framework mvc model and generating dynamic reports

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, model

I am using zend framework to develop my php applications using mvc model.

I want to generate some reports from database. But I don't know how to separate models and views in this case.

I fetch information from db, then I should iterate through them and make a HTML table. Then pass this table to a class, making pdf file from the HTML table.

How should I make this HTML table in my view then pass it to my model and generating pdf file?!

Answer (score 0):

```
//in controller
$this->view->data = $model->getData($parameter);

//in model
pulic function getData($parameter)
{
  $sql = $this->select()->where('parameter = ?',$parameter);
  return $this->fetchAll($sql);
}

//in view
...
foreach($this->data as $item)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>';
  echo $item->name;
  echo '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: as i told, i dont want to echo my table. i want to put my table in a variable and pass the variable to a class method and make a pdf file from it.

Comment: so leave the data as it is and do the "foreach" in your PDF generator :)

Comment: ok, i think i should do this so. but i thought that if i do the foreach in my PDF generator which is a model class and generate html tables in it i am mixing views and models.